# How to execute Power Automate at the successful completion of Azure data factory pipeline?

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-factory, power-automate

I need to create and run Power Automate flow to refresh Power BI dataset at the successful completion of my Azure data factory pipeline.

Flow should not run if data pipeline fails. How could I do it?

Comment: did this work for you?

Comment: thanks. I have yet to try this. is there any simpler solution other than this? this seems I need many privileges and I do not have access to power bi workspace I guess.

Comment: right at the first step for AAD  - it says 'You do  not have access' and the article already warned me that I need many such privileges etc.

Comment: client already has solution in Flow which is based on scheduled time for refresh, and thinks this is small tweak from that to based on trigger of new data arrival

Comment: so you dont have access in lower region like Dev/QA ?

Comment: Dev-Yes. I think the article probably suggested that Dev privileges may not be enough and I need work with admin.

Comment: no, I’m talking about Admin priv in Dev environment.

Comment: although I am convinced that the link you provided is correct solution for the problem. I could accept this once I complete all the required steps. my requests for such privileges is progressing slow

Comment: no does not look like I have it or else I would not see such errors in Dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a Power Automate flow to refresh the Power BI dataset, when ADF pipeline is successful. That can be done directly from ADF pipeline to Power BI dataset.

[How To Trigger A Power BI Dataset Refresh Using An Azure Data Factory Web Activity](https://www.moderndata.ai/2019/05/powerbi-dataset-refresh-using-adf/)

Comment: if The client seem prefer non technical - no code type solution, is it even possible to use flow for this?

Comment: @RajuChoudhari the above is also no code solution only, with one less component. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Do Until** after **Create a pipeline run** activity.
Inside **Do Until** you will have to specify until what(condition) your ***loop*** should run. Here you have to check the if the **Status of the pipeline is not equal to InProgress**. Now the loop should have 2 flows, namely - **get a pipeline run** (to fetch the status) and **delay timer of 10s** to recheck the pipeline status in every 10s. After the do until loop, **set a powerbi refresh** and voila.

[image: 1]